# How to import packages from Anaconda instead of default pip directory

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, importerror

[image]
When using iPython and Jupyter Notebook, the commands

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

always try to import the packages from the default python directory:

```
 C:/Users/sx449_000/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python36/site-packages
```

How can I change it to make it import from my anaconda site packages as below?

```
 C:/programdata/miniconda3/lib/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using the right **kernel** in your ipython notebook, otherwise, you can change it from **kernel >> change kernel**

You can also try,

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append('C:/programdata/miniconda3/lib/packages/numpy')
 import numpy as np
```